# GOLAND Environment Vars in .env file

Tags: intellij-idea, goland

Could anyone say me how to export environment vars before running GoLand Run" with such command:

```
source .env
```

.env file:

```
export MY_VAR="Some value"
```

Yes I know, that I can define all vars in run config using "Environment variables", but it is too, em... bad solution, as I store all vars in bash file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a plugin built for this purpose. It can import`.env` ,`.json` and `.yaml`.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7861-envfile

Answer (score 4):

You can go to Tools | Create command line launcher... and then start GoLand from the command line, which will then inherit those environment variables and pass it to your run configurations.

At the moment this feature is not supported, you can request it on [the issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go).

Comment: If this feature is not supported why does goland charge so much for license?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried envfile plugin, but it didn't work for some reason.
Then I found a simplier solution.

**You can just copy .env file content and use "Paste" button in "Environment Variables" window.**
[button pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdAyk.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).