# How do I configure goland to recognize 'mod' packages?

Tags: go, goland

I am taking go1.11rc1 for a spin and the first thing I noticed is that goland does not recognize imports.

The [goland version announcement](https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2018/07/25/goland-2018-2/) says: "support for Go modules out of the box (formerly known as vgo)"

Anyone know how to fix this?

Problem:

1. Packages like "github.com/urfave/cli" colored red and hover text says: "Cannot resolve directory..."
2. Imported package items like "NewApp" in "app := cli.NewApp()" colored red and hover text says: "Unresolved reference ..."

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install go1.11rc1: remove the current install, install 1.11rc1, check version.
2. Create a new project directory outside the go path: `mkdir pjg && cd pjg`
3. Create a `go.mod` file: `go mod init github.com/stevetarver/pjg`
4. Add a package to the project: `go get github.com/urfave/cli`

`go.mod` file now looks like:

```
module github.com/stevetarver/pjg/v1

require github.com/urfave/cli v1.20.0 // indirect
```

Create `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/urfave/cli"
)

func main() {
    app := cli.NewApp()
    app.Name = "boom"
    app.Usage = "make an explosive entrance"
    app.Action = func(c *cli.Context) error {
        fmt.Println("boom! I say!")
        return nil
    }

    err := app.Run(os.Args)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

View `main.go` in goland, and hover over red text to see problem.

- mod packages are stored in `$GOPATH/pkg/mod/`
- goland version: 2018.2.1
- go version: go1.11rc1 darwin/amd64

Notes:

- `$GOPATH` is set correctly - `go get` put the package in the right place, GOPATH in env matches goland preferences.
- Setting goland preferences Go -> GOPATH -> Module GOPATH to `/Users/starver/code/go/pkg/mod` did not fix this.

Answer (score 84):

The answers on [this site](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008537499-cannot-resolve-directory-of-all-the-import) worked for me. Basically, enable go modules in GoLand via:

> Make sure Go Modules integration is enabled in settings (Preferences / Settings | Go | Go Modules), and GOPATH indexing is disabled (Preferences / Settings | Go | GOPATH | Index entire GOPATH).

As soon as I did this, the red imports went away and everything worked.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer and worked for me too. My go project doesn't have `go.mod` and the steps in https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008537499/comments/360002425559 worked for me.

Comment: I had this turned on and was still seeing the problem described. Turning it off and back on again fixed it.

Answer (score 23):

### GoLand support

The latest version of GoLand implemented support for vgo and go modules, but it hasn't caught up with go1.11rc1 syntax changes. Just in case it helps someone in the interim, I am going to document the things I tried and their problems and successes.

**TL;DR**: Don't put your project inside `$GOPATH` AND create your new project as a "Go Module (vgo)" type, OR turn that setting on for existing projects.

With go1.11rc1 installed as your global `go`, there are three basic use cases for `go mod` projects in GoLand...

#### Create a new project **inside** `$GOPATH`:

1. Create a new project of type "Go Module (vgo)": File -> New, select "Go Module (vgo)"
2. Set your project directory to something inside `$GOPATH`: `$GOPATH/src/github.com/stevetarver/insidegopath`
3. Create your `main.go` file referencing a package that does not exist in your `$GOPATH`.
4. Add that package to your imports.

Using `go get` the GoLand way via `vgo` as described in the gif [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2018/05/18/vgo-integration-support/):

1. Click on the import package.
2. Click on the red inspection bulb.
3. Click on "Sync packages of ...".
4. **FAIL**: `go: go mod -sync is now go mod tidy`

Using `go get` the GoLand embedded terminal way:

1. Open the embedded terminal.
2. `go get` your import.
3. **FAIL**:

   `ᐅ go get github.com/urfave/cli
   go get: warning: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=auto in GOPATH/src;
       ignoring go.mod;
       see 'go help modules'`

Let's turn that variable on and try again:

1. Note: the terminal plugin preferences provide no way to set environment variables.
2. Set `GO111MODULE=on`: Open Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> Path Variables, and add `GO111MODULE=on`.
3. Exit the terminal, retry, restart GoLand, retry, same failure as above.
4. `env | grep GO111MODULE` in the terminal produces nothing.
5. *NOTE*: if this would have worked, it would have been a bad solution - GoLand does not appear to have a per-project settings for this - that variable would have been turned on for all projects which would break those that aren't ready for go modules.
6. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48863587/1089228), you can create a custom command line launcher to include this env var, but eeuuwww - how would you keep track of when to start GoLand normally and when to use the command line launcher?

You could set `GO111MODULE=on` in your shell init script, but that would break all the projects that don't use go modules yet.

You could also prefix each go command with the env var: `export GO111MODULE=on; go get github.com/urfave/cli` or create a `go` shell script wrapper in your project directory that does this for you.

*None of these are really workable solutions, but part of the point of go modules is escape from the dreaded go workspace, so read on, it gets better*

#### Create a new project **outside** `$GOPATH`:

1. Create a new project of type "Go Module (vgo)": File -> New, select "Go Module (vgo)"
2. Set your project directory to something outside `$GOPATH`
3. Fix up your `go.mod`: the generated file contains `module "outsidegopath"`, but we want something like `module github.com/stevetarver/outsidegopath`. This is a bit wonky - GoLand will try to rewrite `go.mod` and remove parts of the path. Repeat a couple times and it will stop trying.
4. Create your `main.go` file. If you create this through the ide as a go file, it will contain `package outsidegopath`. Fix that to be `package main`.
5. Now you can `go get github.com/urfave/cli` and it is fetched to `$GOPATH/pkg/mod` as expected.

#### Add `go mod` support to **an existing new** project:

This turned out to be really simple - best way of working with go modules in GoLand:

1. Open Preferences: Go -> Go Module (vgo), and check "Enable Go Modules (vgo) integration"
2. Works as described above - but you create your own `go.mod` with `go mod init module-name`.

Comment: GoLand will support Go 1.11 RC1 from 2018.2.2, which at the time of writing is next week, and the error ` go: go mod -sync is now go mod tidy ` will be fixed then.

Comment: Thanks for the info @dlsniper - that is an amazingly quick follow up to the new go rc. Note - I am a vocal advocate of JetBrains products and maintain a personal All Products subscription - not finding fault, just sharing in case it helps someone. Previously, JetBrains has published the opinion that they would wait for new language versions to gel before officially supporting new features - pragmatic and reasonable. I thought there might be a quarter before supporting big changes like this were supported and the info would be more durable.

Answer (score 5):

In Jetbrains, Goland.

Go to File -> setting then check the menu as shown in screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I did the same and then invalidated the cache. It is working right now.

Comment: Thanks, this step works for intellij 2019 too

Answer (score 4):

In goland's Settings, checking go module integration solved my pro.

Answer (score 1):

[The module management](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.13#modules) should be easier with Go 1.13 (Aug. 2019):

> The `GO111MODULE` environment variable continues to default to `auto`, but the `auto` setting now activates the module-aware mode of the `go` command whenever the current working directory contains, or is below a directory containing, a `go.mod` file — **even if the current directory is within `GOPATH/src`**.
>
> This change simplifies the migration of existing code within `GOPATH/src` and the ongoing maintenance of module-aware packages alongside non-module-aware importers.

That means the all "Don't put your project inside `$GOPATH`" part will no longer be needed.
As long as there is a `go.mod` file, modules will be recognized, from command-line [or from an IDE like Goland](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below and it solved the problem.
Main Menu > File (Menu) > Invalidate Caches ....
Select all checkboxes Invalidate and Restart.
After restart allow it to sync up and problem should be solved.